# How do I check if MongoDB already contains a document the same field:value pair in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

Here's my code

```
var uEmail = "test@test.com";
var uPass = "testpass";
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/game-news', function(err, db){
    if(err) throw err;
    db.collection('users').insert({email : uEmail,
          password : uPass,
          games: []});
    res.send("success!");
} else {
    res.send("exists")
}});
```

How can I have the user only be added into the database if a document with the same email doesn't exist? Everything I have been trying with mongodb's .find() function has not been successful.

Thanks!

Comment: You "should" try harder then. ["Create a unique index"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/), ["Upsert documents"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option), ["Query Tutorial"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/). This really "looks" like the first code you have written and have not really researched the problem. Do some research. There are links.

Comment: Sorry, Yeah I've been on this for about an hour now. I'm very new to databases, and node.js in general. Must have been googling the wrong things.

Comment: Read the tutorials and folllow the examples before diving in. Just like assembling a bike without following the instructions, you are likely to get things wrong when you do not. You will learn more that way than simply asking someone to write it out for you.

Comment: you can try upsert documents or first find whether the document is present or not using find() method then insert it

Comment: I've managed to create a unique index so no documents with duplicate emails can be added, but I need to be able to send a json response when the insert fails. It doesn't look like it errors when there is a duplicate, and I am having trouble finding a way to get my javascript to know when it wasn't written to the database. Any help?